# SSH pipe include command

Tags: ssh

When I try to run a command on a remote host

```
ssh user@example.com "fswebcam -d /dev/video0 --save -" > img1
```

I always get at the top of the img1 file mixed in

```
^]kfswebcam -r 1280x960 -d /dev/video0 --save -\ÿØÿàJFIFÿþ>CREATOR: gd-jp
```

Which causes the file to no longer be a valid JPEG image

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue.
It's in the fish shell, when I run `/bin/bash ssh user@example.com "fswebcam -d /dev/video0 --save -" > img1` it works perfectly fine.
No mixed up headers in the jpeg image

Comment: I was wondering if it was the shell... Makes since

Answer (score 0):

A rather roundabout way of doing it, but you could use:

```
ssh user@example.com "fswebcam -d /dev/video0 --save -"  | tail -n +2 > img1
```

Comment: `sed 1d` could alternatively be used instead of the head command.

Comment: Won't work - using head -n -1 will get rid of the *last* line of the file, not the first. You want to do this: `ssh user@example.com "fswebcam -d /dev/video0 --save -" | tail -n +2 > img1` EDIT: @hlovdal is correct as well.

Comment: @user55325 Oops! Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: If it had only been that easy, unfortunately it's mixed in. I've updated the question

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be some echo configuration on the `example.com` host. I just tested with `ssh localhost date` and it will just print the date without any echo of the date command. Try to confirm this by running date and check if that also gets a first line of echo.

Try to temporarily disable files like `.bashrc`, `.profile`, etc by renaming or moving out of the home directory and see if you still get echo. Does changing the login shell for `user` to /bin/sh make any difference?

Comment: No, running date is fine. It's only when it's being outputted through pipe it seems. Which is very odd but also indicates it might be my osx behaving odd

Comment: Any pipe? What about `ssh localhost date | cat`?.